# NodeJS with puppeteer Error from Promise Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, puppeteer

I'm developing community auto screen capture app with NodeJS. Actually, It works well with it's screencapture function When I wait for a while it seems got a bug and doesn't work anymore.

I found the error message in console like this.

```
(node:23436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'screenshot' of null
    at C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projects\Bander-Statistics\google.js:60:31
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:23436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23436) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
same data
```

I think the problem are from async function. But I have to wait for a long time to see error message again and I don't know why is this working like this.

This is my full code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request');

let postArray = [];
let uniq = [];
let initNumber;
let prevNumber;

function data() {
    (async () => {
        await request.get({
            url: 'https://www.clien.net/service/group/community'
        }, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            let $ = cheerio.load(body);
            initNumber = $('.list_item.symph_row').attr('data-board-sn');
        })
        if (initNumber === prevNumber) {
            console.log('same data'); // Same Data, Do nothing
            // prevNumber = initNumber; // Compare with prevNumber
        } else {
            postArray.push(initNumber); // Different Data put to Array
            console.log(postArray);
            prevNumber = initNumber; // Compare with prevNumber
        }
        uniq = postArray.reduce(function (a, b) { // Sometimes in postArray have duplicate value so remove it.
            if (a.indexOf(b) < 0) a.push(b);
            return a;
        }, []);
        console.log(uniq);
    })()
}

setInterval(data, 1000); // Interval 1 second because new post's are really uploaded fast

// screenshot function
function screenshot() {
    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        // Adjustments particular to this page to ensure we hit desktop breakpoint.
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1920,
            height: 100000,
            deviceScaleFactor: 1
        });
        if (uniq.length === 0) { // If postArray are 0, Do nothing
            console.log(`This time Array ${uniq.length}`)
            console.log('No Processing this time');
        } else {

            for (let i = 0; i < uniq.length; i++) { //If postArray have value iterate all value to screenshot
                await page.goto(`https://www.clien.net/service/board/park/${uniq[i]}`);
                const overlay = await page.$('.post_view');
                await overlay.screenshot({
                    path: `./image/${uniq[i]}.png`, // save file name with postarray value
                }).catch((err) => console.log(`Processing Image Clear Array INIT again ${err}`)) // Browser Close)   
            }
            postArray = []; // Reset Array
            await browser.close();
        }
        postArray = []; // Reset Array
        await browser.close(); // Browser Close
    })();
}

setInterval(screenshot, 30000); // Interval 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet the problem is that you weren't able to get a `.post_view`. That's why it's null. You could try using `waitForSelector` there.

```js
await page.goto(`https://www.clien.net/service/board/park/${uniq[i]}`);
const overlay = await page.waitForSelector('.post_view').catch((err) => console.log('Unable to get a post_view element'));
if (overlay) 
    await overlay.screenshot({
        path: `./image/${uniq[i]}.png`, // save file name with postarray value
    }).catch((err) => console.log(`Processing Image Clear Array INIT again ${err}`)) // Browser Close)
```

Comment: it will automatically fail if you add waitForSelector and it cannot find the element, so it won't even get to `if` block.

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher changed